# Claims not visible after AWS Cognito Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, awscognitotoken

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, jsonify, request
from flask_awscognito import AWSCognitoAuthentication


application = Flask(__name__)

application.config['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'eu-west-1' 
application.config['AWS_COGNITO_DOMAIN'] = 'https://xxxxxx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com' #seguro
application.config['AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID'] = 'xxxxxx'   
application.config['AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID'] = 'xxxxxxx' 
application.config['AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_SECRET'] = 'xxxxxxx' 
application.config['AWS_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URL'] = 'http://localhost:5000/aws_cognito_redirect'


aws_auth = AWSCognitoAuthentication(application)


@application.route('/')
@aws_auth.authentication_required
def index():
    claims = aws_auth.claims 
    return jsonify({'claims': claims})


@application.route('/aws_cognito_redirect')
def aws_cognito_redirect():
    access_token = aws_auth.get_access_token(request.args)
    return jsonify({'access_token': access_token})


@application.route('/sign_in')
def sign_in():
    return redirect(aws_auth.get_sign_in_url())
```

after sign in it shows the token properly:

[image]

But now if I type `http://localhost:5000/` on the browser it says there is no Token and I have no access to the claims:

[image]

Am I missing something? thanks

Comment: You're missing the part where your frontend includes the token in the authorization header for requests to flask with the access token you just got. By default its completely stateless on the server-side, the client (your SPA or frontend) holds the credentials to authenticate API requests

Comment: can you provide an example of how to include the token in the index?

Comment: It's actually mentioned in the docs: https://flask-awscognito.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth_code.html#client

Comment: That is the part that I do not know how to do: "present a token in each request to Flask endpoint using a HTTP header like Authorization: Basic TOKEN_HERE". I do not know how to do that. Thanks